# Is it possible to see to see all the classes a typeclass is related to? Or at least its subclasses?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I find it very informative and useful to see which instances a class has. It helps me understand what a class is used for and how. Thankfully this information is available both in GHCi (through the `:info <class>` command) and through the doc on Hackage.

For the same reason, I would love to see the relationship between classes: I'd like to get an overview like the one told by [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auyOf.png) for any given class:

[image: this diagram]

Is it possible to ask GHCi, Hackage, or any other tool/service for all the classes a given class is related to?

GHCi's `:info <class>` and Hackage show the superclasses, but not the sub-ones.

Comment: I don’t know of a way, but I could very well imagine the haddocks to list the (known) subclasses in the same way it lists the instances. It is necessary incomplete, as modules not seen by haddock yet can contain more instances and subclasses, but still. Why don’t you file a feature suggestion bug against haddock: https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: just did it. https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/1549

Comment: The module defining the subclass will necessarily import the one defining the superclass, which means the module defining the superclass probably won't import (and thus won't be aware of) many subclasses unless they're in the same module. It's not *impossible* to have module import cycles, and the docs might be arranged to be in separate modules that import both. But it seems likely that many times you wouldn't see any subclasses unless the author has gone to some extra trouble.

Comment: @Ben: true, but the same applies to a class' instances as well, but both GHCi and Hackage can show those.

Comment: @BlueNebula Hackage shows the types that have an instance that's visible in the module. If you're avoiding orphans the instance should be in the same module as either the type definition or the class definition; so instances for "standard" types tend to all be in the module that defines the class (as well as any types in the library's dependencies), which is a nice set to see in Hackage. But typically it won't show you any "downstream" instances. GHCi shows you whatever instances are visible in your current GHCi environment, so you can make it show you instances from any modules you like.

Comment: @BlueNebula So a useful (but far from complete) list of *instances* is usually visible to Hackage in the module defining the class. That will be the case much less often with subclasses. I'm not saying it would be a *bad* feature, but I'm pretty sure it'll be less "transparently" useful - requiring conscious effort from library authors to show anything in a lot of cases.

Comment: Yeah and having that would be enough. For a type class I would like to see one or both of: 1. all its subclasses that are available in my GHCi, 2. all its subclasses which are defined in the same module on Hackage. Of course these lists are going to be incomplete (after all, the set of subclasses and instances is open/unlimited), but I think it would useful for me, especially for those modules that define a lot of classes, like for instance in Prelude/the standard modules.